# make NTFS Junction system hidden on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, ntfs, user-profiles, junction

I'm trying to migrate my user profile to a separate partition, and I've got to the point of adding the compatibility system Junctions to the new profile. However I don't want to see them in my profile so I would like to make the *System Hidden*.

My problem is that the [`attrib` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib) only changes the attribute of the junction's target. I can apply the `hidden` attribute to a junction in Windows Explorer but not the `system hidden` attribute.

Creating system hidden NTFS junctions should be possible though, since the junctions in my original user profile are system hidden. Any thoughts?

I'm on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, don't have Windows 8.1, so this may be different, but on my Windows 10 VM, I see `attrib` has a switch `/L` that may solve your problem.

```
/L  Work on the attributes of the Symbolic Link versus
    the target of the Symbolic Link
```

So for testing, I did something like:

```
> mklink /j sample_shortcut C:\my_target_dir
  Junction created for sample_shortcut <<===>> C:\my_target_dir
> attrib +S +H sample_shortcut /L
```

And I no longer see the junction point I created.

Comment: This also works in Win 7. :-)

Comment: `attrib /L` is supported since Windows Vista.